# Anything wrong with reusing a subset of terminals already used in BNF for an LR lex/parser?

Tags: bnf, lr-grammar

Please excuse my terminology as I am still getting my head wrapped around everything.  I am trying to put together my first parser and have trying to find as many examples as I can to in trying to build my grammar.  I've seen many situations where a non-termianal gets multiplie productions

```
<F>::=(<E>)
<F>::=id
```

Which is the same as writing

```
<F>::id|(<E>)
```

From everything I've read, this is perfectly fine.  What I am looking to do is the following

```
<atsign>::=@
<expl>::=!
<special>::=!|@|#|$|%|^|&|*|(|)|+
```

**Is there anything I need to be mindful of?  Is my ordering correct for an LR parser?**  This isn't exactly homework as I am not in school at the moment, but it can be treated as such since I know this is a course I'll be taking in the future.